# java.io.IOException: Couldn't open

Tags: java, android, parsear, sax

Esto son los errores que me pasa y que hago, un reader y lo intento pasar a un parseado, lo que hago es mandar un dato y me devuelva la cadena en XML pasara asi parsearlo en Sax.

```
    <?php 
$link = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.es", "u126083979_admin", "123456", "u126083979_lugar"); 
     if(isset($_POST['nombre'])) 
     { 
      $nombre = $_POST['nombre']; 
      $query1 = "SELECT * FROM Sitio WHERE Nombre = $nombre"; 
       if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query1)) 
       { 
             echo "<Sitios>"; 
             while($Sitio = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
             { 
              echo "<Sitio>"; 
              echo "<Nombre>" . $Sitio['Nombre'] . "</Nombre>"; 
            echo "<ImagenPrin>" . $Sitio['ImagenPrin'] . "</ImagenPrin>"; 
              echo "</Sitio>"; 
             } 
             echo "</Sitios>"; 
             mysqli_free_result($result); 

       } 
       else 
       { 
         echo "ERROR: $sql. " . mysqli_error($link); 
       } 
     } 
?>
```

Alguna idea de como arreglarlo

```
04-18 18:04:45.530 12331-20851/com.adilosa94.theturistllion W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Couldn't open <Sitios><Sitio><Nombre>Basílica de San Isidoro</Nombre><ImagenPrin>http://theturistllion.hol.es/upload/Imagenes/Sitios%20Principal/san_isidoro.jpg</ImagenPrin></Sitio></Sitios>
    04-18 18:04:45.533 12331-20851/com.adilosa94.theturistllion W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: <Sitios><Sitio><Nombre>Basílica de San Isidoro</Nombre><ImagenPrin>http://theturistllion.hol.es/upload/Imagenes/Sitios%20Principal/san_isidoro.jpg</ImagenPrin></Sitio></Sitios>
```

```html
try {

                int response_code = conexion.getResponseCode();

                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    // Lee los datos enviados desde el php
                    InputStream input = conexion.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    System.out.print("TODO BIEN");
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
                        SaxHandlerSitio handler = new SaxHandlerSitio();
                        parser.parse(line, handler);

                    }

                    return (result.toString());
                } else {
                    return ("suceso");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (SAXException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } finally {
                conexion.disconnect();
            }
            return null;
```

Esta es mi clase deparseo mediante sax handler

```
`
public class SaxHandlerSitio extends DefaultHandler{
    private List<Sitio> sitios;
    private Sitio sitioAc;
    private StringBuilder sbText;
    public Boolean parsingError = false;



    public List<Sitio> getSitios(){
        return sitios;
    }


    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {

        super.startDocument();

        sitios = new ArrayList<Sitio>();
        sbText = new StringBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        super.startElement(uri, localName, name, attributes);

        if (localName.equals("Sitio")) {
            sitioAc = new Sitio(name, 0,0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {

        super.characters(ch, start, length);

        if (this.sitioAc != null)
            sbText.append(ch, start, length);
    }


    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
            throws SAXException {

        super.endElement(uri, localName, name);
        double value;
        int valor = 0;
        if (this.sitioAc != null) {

            if (localName.equals("Nombre")) {
                sitioAc.setNombre(sbText.toString().trim());
            }
            else if (localName.equals("Latitud")) {
                value = Double.parseDouble(sbText.toString().trim());
                sitioAc.setLatitud(value);
            }
            else if (localName.equals("Longitud")) {
                value = Double.parseDouble(sbText.toString().trim());
                sitioAc.setLongitud(value);
            }
            else if (localName.equals("ImagenPrin")) {
                sitioAc.setImagen(sbText.toString().trim());
            }
            else if (localName.equals("Sitio")) {
                sitios.add(sitioAc);
            }
            sbText.setLength(0);
        }
    }

}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es:

```
 Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:
 <Sitios><Sitio><Nombre>Basílica de San
 Isidoro</Nombre><ImagenPrin>http://theturistllion.hol.es/upload/Imagenes/Sitios%20Principal/san_isidoro.jpg</ImagenPrin></Sitio></Sitios>
```

[**MalformedURLException**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/MalformedURLException.html), Lo que debería ser una url, en realidad es una cadena de caracteres que no puede ser representada como Url ya que no inicia con el protocolo `http://`,

```
<ImagenPrin>http://theturistllion.hol.es/upload/Imagenes/Sitios%20Principal/san_isidoro.jpg</ImagenPrin></Sitio></Sitios>
```

debería ser únicamente:

```
http://theturistllion.hol.es/upload/Imagenes/Sitios%20Principal/san_isidoro.jpg
```

**Tienes que asegurar el parser únicamente se obtenga la URL para realizar la conexión!.**

---

Posiblemente necesites cambiar tu página .php de esta forma, para obtener únicamente el url:

```
  if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query1)) 
       { 
            // echo "<Sitios>"; 
             while($Sitio = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
             { 
            //  echo "<Sitio>"; 
              //echo "<Nombre>" . $Sitio['Nombre'] . "</Nombre>"; 
              //echo "<ImagenPrin>" . $Sitio['ImagenPrin'] . "</ImagenPrin>"; 
              echo . $Sitio['ImagenPrin']; 
             // echo "</Sitio>"; 
             } 
            // echo "</Sitios>"; 
             mysqli_free_result($result); 

       }
```

Comment: No hay manera de parsear esto que yo devuelvo en el php independientemente de esa url, que es para pasar y mostrar una imagen esa url que tu me dices, simplemte quitar las etiquetas <Sitios><Sitio><Nombre>Basílica de San
 Isidoro</Nombre><ImagenPrin>http://theturistllion.hol.es/upload/Imagenes/Sitios%20Principal/san_isidoro.jpg</ImagenPrin></Sitio></Sitios>

Comment: <Sitios><Sitio><Nombre>Basílica de San Isidoro</Nombre> y esto como lo puedo parsear y yo meto un valor en la consulta para que me devuelva esto, como puedo hacerlo

Comment: Creo que no me has entendido, yo quiero que me devuelva un String, no una  url. Es decir un xml para poder parsear, independientemente de la url que medecias

Comment: Tu problema es:  Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: se debe a que no envias una url correcta. Ahora comentas que quieres devuelva un String el .php o el parsear la respuesta? **tu pregunta es demasiado amplia entonces**.

Comment: eso es quiero parsear la respuesta, hay alguna manera y perdón que me explico muy mal

Comment: y porque no para iniciar, agregas tu parser?

Comment: ya he agregado mi clase de parseo